# How do I remove unnecessary console message pop up using selenium with Python?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, chromedriver

When I used Chromedriver with selenium in python, I get a lot of console messages that are not useful to me and that don't affect my scraper. How do I not output these? I do not have this issue when I use geckodriver. Please see picture for example of the stuff I don't want.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can run ChromeDriver in **silent mode.**
When you execute ChromeDriver, you have to set the log level in the command line arguments:

```
chromedriver --log-level=OFF
```

**Similar post in (StackOverflow)**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702533/how-to-execute-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-silent-mode

**Edit**

*--log-level=3* offer a minimal amount of logs, but if you want a totally silent mode, it's better to use *--log-level=OFF*